# React map inside map

Tags: reactjs, nested-loops, map-function

```
      {posts.map((post) =>
        posts.comments?.map((comment) => (
          <Posts key={post._id} post={post} comment={comment} />
        ))
      )}
```

I want to be able to do something like this, where I loop through posts and comments and send every comment and post as a **prop** to **Posts** component, but its not working, how can I do it?

Comment: why do you get comment from posts not post? is Right?

Comment: right but it doesn't work, weird things happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with your code, you send every comment seperatly to you Posts component and create a Posts component for every comment.

I think your posts array is something like this:

```
const posts = [{id: 1, comments: [], name: 'post_name', ...}, {...}, ]
```

so you need just one map

```
posts.map(post => {
    return (
        <Posts key={post._id} post={post}/>
    )
})
```

and in Posts component, you have "post" as a prop. just map your post.comments here:

functional component example of Posts:

```
const Posts = ({post}) => {
...

return (
    post.comments.length > 0 && (
        post.comments.map(comment => {
            return (
               <div>{comment}<div/>
            )
        })
    )
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `posts.comments` to `post.comments` inside first map function. I assume that array `comments` is in each object in the main array.

```
{posts.map((post) =>
    post.comments?.map((comment) => (
      <Posts key={post._id} post={post} comment={comment} />
    ))
  )}
```

Comment: right but still doesn't work